# How do I replace the contents of a HTML document with random text using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Here is code that I've written.

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import string, random

def readHtml():
    sock = urllib.urlopen('1041956_Page1.htm')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(sock,'html.parser')
    paraTags = soup.find_all('p')
    for para in paraTags:
        if(para.get_text() is not None):
            para.replace_with(randomizeText(para.get_text())


def randomizeText(text):
    length = len(text)
    newWord = ''.join(random.choice(string.lowercase) for x in range(length-1))
    return newWord

if __name__ == "__main__":
    readHtml()
```

This gives me an error that says

> ValueError: Cannot insert None into a tag.

I want the  BeautifulSoup object to be replaced with random text would like to rebuild the html from it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your code seems to be fine - you may be getting this because of empty p block

Answer (score 1):

Your `randomizeText()` isn't returning anything i.e. `None`. 
Make it:

```
def randomizeText(text):
    length = len(text)
    newWord = ''.join(random.choice(string.lowercase) for x in range(length))
    print newWord
    return newWord
```

and `replace_with` has a restriction of replacing text with `None`.

---

Also change the line 10 from:

```
para.string.replace_with(randomizeText(para.get_text()))
```

to

```
para.replace_with(randomizeText(para.get_text()))
```

to avoid the - **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace_with'**

---

And my above comment

> Your code seems to be fine - you may be getting this because of empty
>   `p` block

is nullified, as i have checked length of empty `p` block is 1.

Comment: I had missed the return statement, but even on providing a return statement, I get an error that states "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace_with'". But a part of the text in the HTML content gets converted

Comment: at line 10 - change para.string.replace_with to para.replace_with

Comment: I just added the check for None type and it seems to work after making the change at line 10. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have also added the second edit in the answer - if issue has been resolved select the answer, 'd be helpful for future uses.

Comment: **para.replace_with(randomizeText(para.get_text()))** is marking the beginning of a new block and everything I write after that statement is throwing syntax error. I've updated the code.

Comment: I noticed that **para.string.replace_with(randomizeText(para.get_text()))** was replacing the string in the para tag and removing the **string** wouldn't do it!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but have you considered the case in which

```
<p></p>
```

is empty.

So,

```
para.get_text()
```

will return None.

Comment: don't think so as it'd have given - TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got NoneType. at newWord generation.